# filter out xml node in record with specific data in it

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am require to create xml file from array list in c#, which is working fine. what i need not to create node in xml for record whose value is coming # in record. so say example if # is this then don't create the node but if value from array list is coming string other than # then create node and store value in it.

many thanks

```
public void generateXMLFile(List<UWL> myList )
{          
        XDocument objXDoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Institution",
         new XElement("RECID", myList[0].recid),
         new XElement("UKPRN", myList[0].UKPRN),
         myList.Select(m => new XElement("Person",
             new XElement("STAFFID", m.STAFFID),
             new XElement("OWNSTAFFID", m.OWNSTAFFID),
             new XElement("ACTCHQUAL", m.ABLWELSH)
             )                      
          )
         )
        );

        objXDoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true");
        //
        objXDoc.Save(@"C:\Test\generated.xml");

        //Completed.......//
        MessageBox.Show("Process Completed......");
}
```

Comment: i am reading data from c# array list and create nodes of xml, now if coming next data is # in array list then don't create node else create and jump to next

Comment: Are you actually looping round the list in the code (and haven't shown us)?

Comment: @doctorlove the `myList.Select(m => new XElement` will add the array of XElement's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what # represents, but say it is one of the values in the Person.  In my example I picked STAFFID, but it could be any of the others or some other value in your UWL object you want to filter by:

Change your `myList.Select` to:

```
myList
.Where(m => m != null)
.Where(m => m.STAFFID != value)
.Select(m => new XElement("Person",
             new XElement("STAFFID", m.STAFFID),
             new XElement("OWNSTAFFID", m.OWNSTAFFID),
             new XElement("ACTCHQUAL", m.ABLWELSH)
             )                      
          )
```

Comment: ok how about if i say, don't create node for null value or if delete all nodes from xml document where value is null

Comment: @toxic when you say `don't create node for null value` what is null the m?  Then you do another `.Where(m => m != null)`